# How to compile cython-compiled c code on Windows using Visual Studio Compilers

Tags: python, visual-c++, cython, python-3.7

I want to compile my python code with cython.
Compilation of my code in cython is without problems, but I can't compile it to executable.

```
cl .\setup.c /I C:\Users\Host\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include
```

And error I am getting is

```
/out:setup.exe
setup.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python37.lib'
```

I am using 64 bit version of Windows 10 and python 3.7

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LNK1104`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1104?view=vs-2019) means the linker could not find `python37.lib` in the default paths set in the `LIB` environment.

To correct that, the directory of `python37.lib` needs to be added to the library search path passed to the linker. Given the posted command line, this would most likely be:

```
cl .\setup.c /I "C:\Users\Host\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include" /link /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\Host\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\libs"
```